# Laravel Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::rememberForever()

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am getting the following errors and I have no idea why rememberForever is undefined.

Here are a couple of common error traces I'm seeing:

```
Error {#4701
  #message: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::rememberForever()"
  #code: 0
  #file: "D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php"
  #line: 261
  trace: {
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:261 {
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic($method, $args) …
      › 
      ›     return $instance->$method(...$args);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\app\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php:120 {
      App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure} …
      ›     return Spotlight::where('homepage', true)->limit(3)->get();\r
      › });\r
      › \r
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:381 {
      Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure} …
      › 
      ›     return $listener(...array_values($payload));
      › };
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:226 {
      Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch($event, $payload = [], $halt = false) …
      › foreach ($this->getListeners($event) as $listener) {
      ›     $response = $listener($event, $payload);
      › 
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesEvents.php:177 {
      Illuminate\View\Factory->callComposer(View $view) …
      › {
      ›     $this->events->dispatch('composing: '.$view->name(), [$view]);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:120 {
      Illuminate\View\View->renderContents() …
      › 
      › $this->factory->callComposer($this);
      › 
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php:91 {
      Illuminate\View\View->render(callable $callback = null) …
      › try {
      ›     $contents = $this->renderContents();
      › 
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:62 {
      Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent($content) …
      › elseif ($content instanceof Renderable) {
      ›     $content = $content->render();
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php:34 {
      Illuminate\Http\Response->__construct($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = []) …
      › 
      › $this->setContent($content);
      › $this->setStatusCode($status);
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory.php:55 {
      Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory->make($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = []) …
      › {
      ›     return new Response($content, $status, $headers);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory.php:85 {
      Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory->view($view, $data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = []) …
      › 
      ›     return $this->make($this->view->make($view, $data), $status, $headers);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\app\Exceptions\Handler.php:65 {
      App\Exceptions\Handler->render($request, Throwable $exception) …
      › if ($this->shouldReport($exception)) {\r
      ›     return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);\r
      › }\r
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:51 {
      Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->handleException($passable, Throwable $e) …
      › 
      › $response = $handler->render($passable, $e);
      › 
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:172 {
      Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} …
      › } catch (Throwable $e) {
      ›     return $this->handleException($passable, $e);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103 {
      Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Closure $destination) …
      › 
      ›     return $pipeline($this->passable);
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:140 {
      Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter($request) …
      ›                 ->through($this->app->shouldSkipMiddleware() ? [] : $this->middleware)
      ›                 ->then($this->dispatchToRouter());
      › }
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:109 {
      Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle($request) …
      › 
      ›     $response = $this->sendRequestThroughRouter($request);
      › } catch (Throwable $e) {
    }
    D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\public\index.php:57 {
      › $response = $kernel->handle(\r
      ›     $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()\r
      › );\r
    }
  }
}
```

The second common trace:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#44
  -error: array:4 [
    "type" => 1
    "message" => """
      Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::rememberForever() in D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:261\n
      Stack trace:\n
      #0 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\app\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php(120): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()\n
      #1 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(381): App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}()\n
      #2 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(226): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}()\n
      #3 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesEvents.php(177): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch()\n
      #4 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(120): Illuminate\View\Factory->callComposer()\n
      #5 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\fr
      """
    "file" => "D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php"
    "line" => 261
  ]
  #message: """
    Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::rememberForever() in D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:261\n
    Stack trace:\n
    #0 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\app\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php(120): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()\n
    #1 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(381): App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}()\n
    #2 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(226): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}()\n
    #3 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesEvents.php(177): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch()\n
    #4 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(120): Illuminate\View\Factory->callComposer()\n
    #5 D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\fr
    """
  #code: 0
  #file: "D:\CustomDomains\HolidayBuilders\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php"
  #line: 261
}
```

Here's the code in my **ComposerServiceProvider@boot** method:

```
    view()->composer([
        'welcome',
        'web.metropolitan-detail',
        'web.city-detail',
        'web.community-detail',
        'web.community-detail-parent',
        'web.inventory-detail',
        'web.move-in-ready',
        'web.communities',
        'web.search',
        'errors.500'
    ], function ($view) {
        $view->with([
            'spotlights' => Cache::rememberForever('spotlights', function () {
                return Spotlight::where('homepage', true)->limit(3)->get();
            }),
            'testimonials' => Cache::rememberForever('testimonials', function () {
                return Testimonial::limit(3)->get();
            }),
        ]);
    });
```

I'm on Laravel 7. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: pls check source at (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository.php), see if you have the method there. If not run composer update see if it helps or not.

Comment: try running a `composer update laravel/framework -W` (assuming your composer.json has "laravel/framework": "^7.0",  Just to make sure you are on the latest laravel 7.  Maybe it came out in a later version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you need to use `composer` to rebuild the cache of the vendor classes loaded into your project. To accomplish this try using:

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

Them:

```sh
php artisan optimize && php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

There are commits in Laravel framework that has not implemented the method. So in case the method doesn't exist in source at:

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository.php

you need to update the framework.

```sh
composer update laravel/framework
```